# Error WKB structure does not match expected size

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.6

WKB structure does not match expected size!

Error:  WKB structure does not match expected size!
context:  COPY tn_ctrln, line 966215, column object_gt: "01050000203B140000010000000102000000FD3100008838D655056D3041081B9E9EFEB33A41787AA57C016D304190B96BA9..."

Postgresql 9.6 + PostGIS 3.1.2 is in use.

This error occurred while restoring dump files.

What should I do to solve this problem?
The dump file needs to be restored normally.

Comment: Are you perhaps storing empty multpolygons? If it is not too large, could you post the wkt / ewkt of the "problematic" geometry?

Answer (score 2):

That is a sign of data corruption. Either the data in the original database are corrupted, or the dump file got mangled during transfer.

For an exact diagnosis, you need the exact problematic lie from the dump file.